# Alternative to MS Access

Tags: database, microsoft-access

I am using MS Access for my small office for data management and reporting. I was good with RAD feature of this software e.g. quick form design for data entry and reporting but now a days I am disappeared that I am facing a problem while I need to generate multipage (1-12+) page reporting for a record.To be cleared I need to make 1-12 or more page report created from a single record of an access table. Basically in this report I simply place some exact field value and some calculated value from those fields for a single record.

So now is there any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

Back when I learned Access ('97) there was a report builder that would let you do exactly what you are asking... Build a select query, build a report just like you build input/interface forms, associate it with the query, and it should do it.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-simple-report-408E92A8-11A4-418D-A378-7F1D99C25304

Aside from that, to work in any other DB engine you'd need to export the data out.  The only Easy Way Microsoft provides is to "upsize" the Access DB to a MS SQL server, at which point the Access app will be your front end.  Once it is in MS SQL, the options for getting it out and into some other system expand (ie, do it in PHP or Java to go from MS SQL to MySQL or IBM DB2, etc)

But I really think that using the Access report generation will do what you want, much easier.